# Navigate to a particular slide in PowerPoint Add-In

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, add-in

Using following code, I managed to jump to a particular slide in SlideShow-View [using code from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33143042/2534450):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation objPres;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowView objSlideShowView;

objPres = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;
objPres.SlideShowSettings.ShowPresenterView = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
objPres.SlideShowSettings.Run();
objSlideShowView = objPres.SlideShowWindow.View;                

int index = Int32.Parse(clickedIssue.ToolTip.ToString());               

objSlideShowView.GotoSlide(index);
```

but what I actually want, is that it jumps to a particular slide in Normal-View. I know I can get the currently selected slide using `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide` but how do I change its reference with code?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend to use

```
int SlideIndex = 3;
try
{
  Globals.YourAddin.Application.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide(SlideIndex);
}
catch { }
```

**.Select()** caused me strange issues, where PowerPoint slowed down its performance ..

Comment: Agree with `GoToSlide()`, it is definitely the way to go if you want to change the active slide *without* affecting focus on your Addin's UI controls.
`Slide.Select()` caused issues for me with my controls not entering edit mode, introducing a "double-click needed" behavior when a slide was Select()ed from a control's event handler.

Comment: Thanx man, that's exactly what i need..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using this code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation objPres;
int index = Int32.Parse(clickedIssue.ToolTip.ToString());

objPres = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;
var slides = objPres.Slides;

slides[index].Select();
```

which is the same as [the code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19590043/2534450).

Answer (score -2):

```
Sub gothere()

On Error Resume Next

ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 2

If Err <> 0 Then ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 2

End Sub
```